# How can I improve the sophistication of my Chinese grammar usage?

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, chinese, grammar

I'm starting to become aware of a weakness in my Chinese grammar.  While in my speaking and writing I'm generally grammatically correct (of course, not always), I don't often use more sophisticated grammatical structures (which is particularly relevant in writing); I'm thinking things like:

> 随着时间的推移，……。
> ……对于……至关重要。
> ……在……中扮演着不可或缺的角色。

The resources I'm aware of, like the [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Main_Page) generally take a bottom-down approach, and analyze individual words.  However, I'm more interested in improving my knowledge of such structures from the top down, i.e., studying not just individual words, but jointly with their collocations.

I'm interested in both finding resources where I can study more sophisticated grammar structures, and learning about methods for studying them.

**Question**: How can I improve the sophistication of my Chinese grammar usage?

Comment: @Tommi How can you improve the sophistication of usage? This is not answerable per se. It can only be a personal narrative, not a repeatable "thing". And I have never heard of methods for studying more sophisticated grammar structures. I know an Austrian lady who lived in Hong Kong who started studying Chinese at 50 and by the time she was 60 she was interpreting from Chinese to English. How did she do it? By slogging away at it, that's how. You read and listen to people speaking the language and write down what you don't know.

Comment: You can post that as an answer. That a question is hard does not mean it is not appropriate for the site, and answers based on literature and personal experiences are both accepted as good answers.

Comment: @Tommi It is just my **opinion**. I don't think the question is very good...

Comment: @Tommi I did not say the question was not "appropriate", did I? Take a look at what the only answer to this question says, and from a native Chinese speaker...

Answer (score 0):

As a Chinese person, I don't know how to explain to get the advanced Chinese grammatical structure for non native speakers.

But from elementary school to university, we do read and recite a lot of study materials like politics, history, literature, etc., then those advanced grammatical structures are all imprinted on our minds naturally.